# matching sub arrays on array and count them

Tags: php, arrays

i am having an array

```
 Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

and i need to find the common subarrays

In the above example array 1 and 3 have the common sub array

```
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 3
)
```

So the final array must be

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

But i need to count the common values some how.

Any suggestion.

Comment: is `array(1,3) == array(3,1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare each element of array with other assuming them as a linear array but use **[`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff)** to compare each element. If they are different copy the element or array index into another array

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use this for production code, but here's a quick & somewhat clever way to do it:

```
$arrays = array(array(1,3), array(1,2), array(1,3)); // Your example data

$serialized = array_map('serialize', $arrays);
$counts = array_count_values($serialized);
foreach ($counts as $data => $count) {
  echo "$count: " . print_r(unserialize($data), true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To isolate unique rows, use the `SORT_REGULAR` flag with `array_unique()`.

To acquire the number of duplicated rows, subtract the unique count from the initial count.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/78PHM))

```
$array = [[1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3]];
$count = count($array);
$unique = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
echo "Number of duplicated rows: " . ($count - count($unique));
```